# Dynamically filtering rxjs stream

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using RXJS and I'm looking to dynamically filter the data, but I'm having problems:

```
let numberSource: ReplaySubject<Number> = new ReplaySubject<Number>();
let numberFilter: BehaviorSubject<Number> = new BehaviorSubject<Number>(5);

let filteredData = numberSource.filter(n => n < numberFilter.value);
numberFilter.subscribe(newFilter => {
  filteredData = numberSource.filter(n => n < newFilter);
  filteredData.subscribe(console.log);  // <- I think this is wrong
});

console.log("A");
filteredData.subscribe(console.log);

numberSource.next(1);
numberSource.next(10);
numberSource.next(100);

console.log("B");
numberFilter.next(50);
```

What I am doing is subscribing to numberSource, that is the data I am interested in displaying. I am also subscribing to numberFilter, because I want any changes to that to replay the subject, but I think I have done that wrong.

I am expecting to see:

```
A
1
B
1
10
```

I am seeing:

```
A
1
1
B
1
10
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: For a start, I'm quite sure you shouldn't subscribe `console.log` to `filterData` each time the subscriber for `numberFilter` runs.

Comment: can you do a marble diagram of what you want to achieve ? That marble diagram would have two input streams and one output stream. As written, the code is quite clumsy stream-speaking-wise (nesting subscribe is a bad practice) and it is hard to understand what you want to do

Comment: @alex yeah that does seem wrong to me too! I wasn't sure how I could rekick the output however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. You want to stack all value emitted by `numberSource` to be able to reemit and filter them when `numberFilter` changes.

The major problem in your implementation is that `numberFilter` is a `BehaviorSubject` which emits its default value (`5` in this case) every time you subscribe to it which happens right on the line `numberFilter.subscribe(newFilter => ...`. This callback subscribes to `filteredData` and then again right after `console.log("A");`. So you haven't even started emitting data to `numberSource` and you've already subscribed twice. That's why it gives you `1` two times.

Easy solution is to use classic `Subject` and remember to `unsubscribe()` the previous subscription to `filteredData`:

```
let numberSource: ReplaySubject<Number> = new ReplaySubject<Number>();
let numberFilter: Subject<Number> = new Subject<Number>();

var subscription;
numberFilter.subscribe(newFilter => {
  if (subscription) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  subscription = numberSource.filter(n => n < newFilter)
    .subscribe(console.log);
});

numberFilter.next(5);

console.log("A");

numberSource.next(1);
numberSource.next(10);
numberSource.next(100);

console.log("B");
numberFilter.next(50);
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vOaD8tcWlLRdfzU14Ufw

Now it gives you the output you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, and your solution does work! Is the unsubscribe/subscribe method the idiomatic rxjs way of doing this?

Comment: @DanDan Since you want to be able to repeat the entire series of data, that this seems like the best way to do it. I don't see a problem with subscribing and unsubscribing, that's at the end `ReplaySubject`'s main purpose to be able to repeat the sequence.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Still trying to get my head around all of this.