# Subscribe to event emitter when array is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following code:

```
this.itemsService.getItems()
    .subscribe(i => this.items = i);
```

But, the user can select a type of item, so I have an event emitter for this:

```
this.typeofitems.selectedType.subscribe(type => this.type = type);
```

and it is working well.

Now I want to filter the list of items `this.items` with the `filter function`. The problem is, I don't know when the loading of items is completed, altough if I put a log in the subscription:

```
this.itemsService.getItems()
    .subscribe(i => {this.items = i; console.log("completed");});
```

it indicates me that's completed. So I tried:

```
this.itemsService.getItems()
    .subscribe(i => {
        this.items = i;
        this.typeofitems.selectedType.subscribe(type => {
            this.type = type;
            this.filterByType();
        });
    });

filterByType() {
    this.itemsfilteredByType = this.items.filter(i => i.type === this.type)
}
```

But it is not working. So I think I can not subscribe inside a subscriptor.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're using `=` instead of `==` in the `filter()` callback so make sure this wasn't the problem.

Anyway, you can use operator [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) that emits a value every time any of it's sources emit a value (while at least one value from each source has to be emitted):

```
function getItems() {
  return Observable.of([{type: 1, val: 345}, {type: 2, val: 107}, {type: 1, val: 926}, {type: 2, val: 456} ]);
}

let typeOfItems = new Subject();

Observable.combineLatest(getItems(), typeOfItems)
  .subscribe(vals => {
    let [items, typeOfItem] = vals;

    let results = items.filter(i => i.type == typeOfItem);
    console.log(results);
  });

typeOfItems.next(2);
```

This filters items by `type == 2` and prints to console:

```
[[object Object] {
  type: 2,
  val: 107
}, [object Object] {
  type: 2,
  val: 456
}]
```

It works thanks to `combineLatest()` which first receives all items and then I tell it to filter them by `type == 2` using `typeOfItems.next(2);` which triggers call to the callback for `combineLatest()` that uses `Array.filter()` to actually filter and print filtered items (note this is  `Array.fitler()` and not `Observable.filter()`).

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/nenosiy/5/edit?js,console

Btw, of course you can `subscribe()` inside another `subscribe()` callback. Just remember you have to manually unsubscribe previous subscribtions.

See a very similar question: [Dynamically filtering rxjs stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533450/dynamically-filtering-rxjs-stream/40535017#40535017)

Comment: The thing is: when the typeOfItems change, will it call to getItems again?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores Why don't you try it for yourself? Just add `typeOfItems.next(1);` at the end and see what happens.